# My script is not triggering all emails based on timer

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Heres a link to the google sheet with the script - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qw8WefbVkS-AQXi1CcZ0z2CL-P0oNSZYqeT40oVF6go/edit#gid=0

I've set the script to trigger every minute to test if the emails are being issued. The script is running with no errors and the executions are showing its running every minute however I am not receiving the emails automatically.

The reason for the script is to remind a party when a process is due for review

I would like to be able to continually add data and have repeated emails in which it would send multiple emails about different processes to the same party. The script should be able to run daily and sent emails automatically. I changed the trigger to every minute to check if I would receive the emails however none have arrived. Please can someone help.

#### Code:

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]!=''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'reminder ... week', 
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The process for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,7).setValue('sent')
    }
    else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][5]!=''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'reminer ... month', 
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The process for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the process team before its due date if amendments are required'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setValue('sent')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1)try to run the code without trigger and see if emails are getting sent correctly
2)check the trigger executions if there is any error log messages
3)if total execution time >6min the execution gets stopped automatically may be the trigger execution had crossed this limit and couldn't run the send mail part
4)one suggestion, set up log messages at crucial points of the code so that you can track them easily in the trigger execution log message

Comment: Attempted to run the code without a trigger an no emails were received. When checking the executions I can see it is running but its not showing as any errors. I ran the trigger for every minute. When manually inputting the word "sent" into columns 6 and 7 it runs and then sends and email, however it continues to send emails continously at that point. Once sent is in the box it should stop sending further email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

Columns `F` and `G` are empty for all rows, so `data[i][6]!=''` and `data[i][5]!=''` will always be `false`. Because of this, the code will never enter the `if` and `else if` blocks, and therefore won't send any email.

#### Solution:

I'm not sure what the conditions for sending the email should be, but I guess you want to send an email in two different situations:

- `Date for Next Review` is between 5 and 7 days after current date, and column `G` is empty.
- `Date for Next Review` is between 28 and 30 days after current date, and column `F` is empty.

If that's the case, you should modify that last condition for both situations, since you want to send the email when column `G` (or `F`) is empty, not when it is populated.

That is to say, replace this:

```
if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]!=''){
```

With this:

```
if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]==''){
```

And this:

```
else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][5]!=''){
```

With this:

```
else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][5]==''){
```

Comment: That has worked flawlessly thank you